# what difference between data and datatype in jquery?

Tags: ajax, jquery

i confuse between `data` and `datatype` in jquery.

```
    $.ajax({
    url:"/challenge/results",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: form_data,
    cache:false,
    success: function(data, textStatus){
        console.log("data!", data, textStatus);
    });
```

Comment: That's what docs for... :) here you go http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: `datatype`: "**Type:** String; *The **type** of data that you're **expecting back** from the server.*" `data`: "**Type:** PlainObject or String; ***Data** to be sent **to** the server.*" Could you clarify exactly what you don't understand about these two vastly different parameters?

Comment: i'm newbie at jquery & jsp (i'm a .net programmmer)... :D.i want to learn about web programming. i copied it from other person code.
No, i have understood what you explain. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**dataType** tells the request what kind of data it expects to receive from the server action . In your case it's json but it could also be xml, html, jsonp, text, or script.

**data** is the actual form data your ajax request is passing to the server action

See [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for details

Answer (score 2):

"dataType" tells method in what format you want response. and "data" is parameters you want to send by get or post method.

see complete documentation of jquery ajax on http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Take example for login throgh ajax.
ex :

```
$.ajax({
url:"login.php",
dataType:"json",
type:"post",
data:{
username:"username", //you will get this values from any variable.
password:"password"
},
success:function(data){

//here data will be on json format say {success : "true",token:"12345"}

}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The dataType is just a definition of what the data is. So in your code example there, you're expecting the data form_data to be in json format and jquery will parse it into an object. Without that data type it's going to return a string instead of an object.

Comment: Well, without the data type jQuery will guess the type depending on the content type that is returned. If the content type is correct for the data, jQuery will still parse it as JSON, but if you specify the data type you are sure what's happening.